# C# Adding "'" Symbol to statements

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a statement that sets a scheduled event, although I am having trouble wrapping the last part of the statement with the ' symbols.

```
Process.Start("schtasks.exe", @"/Create /SC DAILY /MO" + " \"" + comboBox2.Text + "\" " + @"/ST" + " \"" + comboBox1.Text + "\" " + @"/TN" + " \"" + textBox2.Text + "\" " + @"/TR  ""C:\Program Files\test\scan.exe"" " + textBox3.Text);
```

I am trying to get textBox3.Text as follows:

'textBox3.Text'

Comment: You can just place single quotes within your double quotes? "'" + textBox3.Text + "'"

Comment: Are you sure you need single quotes and not double quotes?

Comment: As a side note: Using string.Format would make your code more readable.

Comment: for more clarity, use string.Format(). eg. string.Format("'{0}'", textBox3.Text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the ' inside double quotes.

```
... + "'" + textBox3.Text + "'"
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also use String.Format

```
String.Format("Blah blah '{0}'", textBox3.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Process.Start("schtasks.exe",
              string.Format(
                  @"/Create /SC DAILY /MO ""{0}"" /ST ""{1}"" /TN ""{2}"" /TR  ""C:\Program Files\test\scan.exe"" {3}",
                  comboBox2.Text, comboBox1.Text,
                  textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text));
```